# Qt handling of keyevents

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to write a console widget to my graphic program in C++. I am making the console widget a child widget to the widget acting as a main window. The console is a QDockWidget that holds a QTextEdit. **What I want to do is to handle events when the Return key is pressed from the ConsoleWidget and then handle the command, all other key events should be handleded by the QTextEdit**. The problem is that I am not able to catch any key events except events like Command and Shift keys... Any ideas?

This is the code for the console:

```
class ConsoleWidget : public QDockWidget
{
public:
    ConsoleWidget( const QString& sTitle, QWidget* pParent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags nFlags = 0 );
    ~ConsoleWidget();

protected:
    void keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent* pEvent );
    void keyReleaseEvent( QKeyEvent* pEvent );

private:
    QTextEdit* m_pTextArea;
};


ConsoleWidget::ConsoleWidget( const QString& sTitle, QWidget* pParent, Qt::WindowFlags nFlags ) :
        QDockWidget( sTitle, pParent, nFlags )
{
    setFocusPolicy( Qt::StrongFocus );
    m_pTextArea = new QTextEdit( this );
    setWidget( m_pTextArea );
}

ConsoleWidget::~ConsoleWidget()
{
    // Qt is taking ownership of pTextWidget... (I think)
}

void ConsoleWidget::keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent* pEvent )
{
    if( pEvent->key() & Qt::Key_Return )
    {
        int i = 666;
    }
    else
    {
        pEvent->setAccepted( false );
        // TODO Should I do this if not handling the event?
        //QDockWidget::keyPressEvent( pEvent );
    }
}

void ConsoleWidget::keyReleaseEvent( QKeyEvent* pEvent )
{
    QDockWidget::keyReleaseEvent( pEvent );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, for this case, installEventFilter() would be the way to go, as Troubadour said. Have it "eat" the Return key. And what about the numpad Key_Enter? Maybe catch that too?

Answer (score 3):

You need to subclass `QTextEdit` and override the `keyPressEvent` method there. Remember the `QTextEdit` class will be consuming most key events and so they will not be getting propagated up to the parent dock widget.

Alternatively you could install an event filter. The [docs](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qobject.html#eventFilter) give a good example. In your case your custom dock widget class could be the event filter for the `QTextEdit` so that your logic is all in that class.